# How to create always on process?

Tags: c++, service, windows-services

Situation: We have a backup server and HDD space might be filled in 5 mins.

What do I want to do? I am trying to create a monitoring system that will monitor the space every 2 to 3 mins and will send mail if the free space is less than X GB.

Question: What is the best way to develop such a system? How my EXE will run continuously? It should also startup automatically when the server starts.

I will be using C++

Note: Please do NOT suggest any existing monitoring service/process. We need to develop this for our framework.

** Update :
This is my code :**

```
void  ServiceMain(DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR* lpszArgv)
{
    WinService WinService_o;

    gSvcStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(
        SVCNAME,
        ServiceControlHandler);

    if (!gSvcStatusHandle)
    {
        WinService_o.SvcReportEvent( (LPTSTR) TEXT("RegisterServiceCtrlHandler"));
        return;
    }

    gSvcStatus.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    gSvcStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;

    WinService_o.ReportServiceStatus(SERVICE_START_PENDING, NO_ERROR, 3000);

    WinService_o.PerformService(dwArgc, lpszArgv);

}



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello!\n";

     WinService WinService_o;

     if (argc > 1)
     {
         if (strcmp(argv[1], "-install") == 0)
         {
             printf("Starting the installation process\n");

             WinService_o.DeleteSvc();
             WinService_o.SvcInstall();
             return 1; 

         }
     }


    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY DispatchTable[] = 
    {
        { (LPWSTR)SVCNAME, (LPSERVICE_MAIN_FUNCTION)ServiceMain },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };


    if (!StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW(DispatchTable))
    {
        cout << "test";

        WinService_o.SvcReportEvent( (LPTSTR) TEXT("StartServiceCtrlDispatcher"));

    }
```

But, it's failing to start the service with the following error. I can see the error on event

> StartServiceCtrlDispatcher failed with 1063

Can someone please help?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to tell you, that stack overflow doesn't work that way. We will help you with explicit coding issues. But we can't tell you what to do on this too broad question. You can't expect us to do your job.

Comment: One answer I can give, is on the running continuously part... Use a `while(true)` loop. maybe you should also have a look into `sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question when you tagged it as [windows-services](/questions/tagged/windows-services):

> **Windows services are background service processes** run by the Service Control Manager on Windows NT based operating systems, similar to daemons or UNIX services.

Write your app as a **service**. A service runs in the background, even when no user is logged in, and can be set to auto-start with the OS. What you are asking for is exactly the kind of situation that a service is well suited for.

See [Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services) and [Service Programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-programs) on MSDN for more details and complete C/C++ examples.

Comment: @John it wasn't a suggestion. It is the correct solution you are looking for